# Watson speech to text using Postman

Tags: postman, speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to transcribe an audio using the French model, this is my curl command:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:*********************************"
--header "Content-Type: audio/mp3"
--data-binary @C:\Users\nlouhichi.EXCHANGE\Downloads\Anne-SophieRobert.mp3
"https://api.eu-gb.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/*****/v1/recognize?model=fr-FR_BroadbandModel&timestamps=true&max_alternatives=3&interim_results=true"
```

I couldn't get it to work, even when I change the file and use the sample presented in the following tutorial: [This](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-gettingStarted#getting-started-tutorial)

I always keep getting this error "Stream was 72 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes"
If I change the file a smaller one, it's gonna be the same but for example "Stream was 23 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes. 
What's this stream how can I control it or resize it? 
Or is it me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As `\` is an escape character you need to escape all `\` as `\\` in your Windows path.